# Text from CoreData is not always drawn

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, ios5

I've been working with CoreData and it seems I don't understand it completely yet - my app is loading some data from `CoreData` and filling a `UITableView` with it. Everything seems fine except sometimes no text is drawn. Other data are images and those are always drawn. Until user scrolls a table, no text will show.

I've tried to set my requests to not return faults:

```
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```

However, the problem remains, although it is more infrequent.

Images are build in background from `NSData`. Text is just set to some `UILabel`. Should be text somehow manipulated with, too? How?

As text is correctly shown in console, issue might be in `UITableView` rather than in `CoreData`, but I've failed to find any reason for it.

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your description I suspect this is not a Core Data issue. Faulting cannot be a factor here because Core Data does a round-trip to persistent store to fetch the property on-demand.

Do you use standard UITableViewCells with textLabel and detailTextLabel or do you have custom cell layout?

Could it be that you need to set setNeedsDisplay? Did I understand correctly that in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method NSLog statements succeed to show your text?

Comment: I'm using custom cells and yes, you understood everything correctly. I haven't tried setNeedsDisplay, so if bug doesn't appear for some time, I guess you solve it. :) I was very persistent about bug being in my handling of CoreData - do you think, the 'setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO' is not needed then? Thanks.

Comment: -setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO is absolutely not needed.

Comment: Commented out now and you're right - everything works. I wasn't able to reproduce the bug even once. Seems you've really solved it. Thanks a lot!